# Using funcunit to test a popup window

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

I am using FuncUnit to test a small application I wrote. I have a button that will open a popup window (using the JavaScript function window.open(...)). I can get FuncUnit to press the button and open the pop up window,but I'm not sure how to proceed in order to get a handle on the popup window and do further testing.

Unfortunately, I cannot change any of the code in the pop up,

Thank you,

Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`open` returns a reference to the created window's `window` object. So you can simply use that to access anything in the window. Not sure if you can verify that it has finished loading if you can't modify the popup. Also note that both windows must be on the same domain in order for you to access it.

Comment: So does that mean that I cannot test a webpage that is located on a separate domain? If for example I had a Twitter button to post a link on twitter and wanted to step through that window, it wouldn't be possible?

Comment: Perhaps there is some way to to x-domain communication with browser scripting (instead of scripting webpages). Perhaps with greasemonkey or something similar. But using regular scripts, no.